# Sequelize-Postgres error: values.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working on Node + Postgres app and I have trouble in setting the DataType.ARRAY using Sequelize model schema.

Here is my model schema,

```
var ArtistRoles = sequelize.define('ArtistRoles', {
    id:{
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1
    },
    name:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    tags: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      defaultValue: []
    }
  },{
    hooks:{
      beforeCreate: function (role, options) {
        //role.tags = JSON.stringify(role.tags);
        console.log(role.tags);
      }
    },
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        // add relations model relations here
        //ArtistRoles.belongsTo(models.Artists);
      }
    }
  });
```

I used Postman to test the API and here is how I POST the data to server,
[image]
Here is the Error trace on Node console.

```
TypeError: values.map is not a function
    at ARRAY.BaseTypes.ARRAY.$stringify (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js:385:33)
    at ARRAY.ABSTRACT.stringify (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/data-types.js:77:17)
    at Object.escape (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:967:32)
    at Object.insertQuery (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:299:28)
    at QueryInterface.insert (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:497:33)
    at .<anonymous> (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance.js:672:56)
    at tryCatcher (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (~/PROJECTS/my-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
POST /api/1.0/role 500 46.114 ms - 45
```

What could be the reason? Please help.

Comment: could you share your `data-types.js`? or at least some lines around line no 385?

Answer (score 5):

For *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, the body of the HTTP message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string.

So, the value of *tags* will be in string format when received in backend.
Convert it back into Array type in backend and you should be good to go

Comment: THIS! Working on this for an hour now. This was the answer, just type casted the array using, "args.list = Array(args.list)", and passed it into the validation function along with the schema and error message, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is late, but I had this same issue using Postman even when my tests were passing. I realized that I had to write each of my array values as a different key-value with the keys having the same name as seen in the diagram in the link.

[Postman Key-Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfQEV.png)

Postman will return keys with the same name as an array and Sequelize Postgres Array data-type will ONLY receive Arrays. I realized this from reviewing the data-types.js file.

However, if only one value is entered in Postman, it will be returned as a normal string and Sequelize will reject it, which is what happened. Sequelize is sending the value as a string as **@mdsadiq**  said. You can either convert back to an array in the backend or enter multiple key-values. Either way, you should add a beforeCreate hook that creates an array from that value or Sequelize will reject it as I made in the Image.

[Before Create Hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEUjI.png)

I guess the same goes for the array string, you can convert it in the hook before sending to the database. I have not implemented it in the Front End through a form yet, so I'm not sure about how that will play out. I hope this helps someone and corrections will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resArr = [];
var s =" [{'id':1,'name':'Test1'},{'id':2,'name':'Test2'}]";
var myObject = eval('(' + s + ')');
for (i in myObject)
{
  resArr.push(myObject[i]["name"]);
}
```

Use resArr as request array. Hope it will solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

In postman , if you adding data from form_data then try this ,
*****use JSON.parse(req.body.tags) , in your code.*****

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

the issue is in postman request, just try to send the same request with raw

```
 {
    "name" : "Vocal",
    "tags" : ["Carnatic", "Classical"]
 }
```